# Serve file from post request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a post request to a server to generate an xls file. I need to use a post request as I am submitting some relatively complex JSON which informs how the XLS file is generated. I have the follow controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetExcelData(ReportingRequest reportingRequest)
    {
         // Generate file ....

         Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
         return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/xls");  
    }
```

Which correctly generates an XLS file. I then need to be able to serve the file for download to the client. I'm using JavaScript to post json to the controller. I'm aware that downloads can't be started via ajax requests - what is the best way for me to serve this file for download? The ReportingRequest object is complex and hard to turn into query paramters.

Comment: If the option is available : save the file to disk/db assigning a guid to it ; return the guid as json result ; use the guid client-side to generate a link or the src of a dynamically generated iframe which will serve the file